# How do I append new objects to a list in this example?

Tags: python

Whenever an instance of a class I made is created, I want to append the object to a list of objects held by another object.

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        self.canvas = []
    def create_bum(self, name):
        MyInstance(name)
    def spank_all(self):
        for butt in self.canvas:
            print ("You spanked " + butt.name)

class MyInstance:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        Something.canvas.append(self) # How do I do this?

foo = Something()
foo.create_bum("bob")
foo.create_bum("alice")
foo.spank_all()
```

Comment: ...butt slapping program. Interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it mostly right, just one line in the wrong place. Modify your `create_bum` function to look like this:

```
def create_bum(self, name):
    self.canvas.append(MyInstance(name))
```

You can then remove the following line from your `MyInstance` class’s `__init__` function:

```
Something.canvas.append(self)
```